# Alter sequence .nextval in Oracle SQL 11 with prepared statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g, prepared-statement, java-6

I'm trying to advance a sequence by a negative number but I keep getting the following error:

> ORA-02286: no options specified for ALTER SEQUENCE

So far no amount of Googling has helped. The statement that I use is

```
ALTER SEQUENCE %s.nextval INCREMENT BY ?
```

The sequence name is generally `schema.table_name_seq`. Including the schema name is unavoidable because the connection is not necessarily to the same one.

Appending an inconsequential option like `minvalue 1` did nothing to satisfy it either.

My second attempt was to drop `.nextval` from the query and run `ALTER` directly on the sequence (just throwing stuff at the wall to see what sticks at this point), ie:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE %s INCREMENT BY ?
```

which results in

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Next I supplied a positive integer and negated it in the query (`INCREMENT BY -?`) which produced the same error. The query is prepared as such:

```
num = -1 * Math.abs(num);

stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setLong(1, num); //also tried setInt()
stmt.execute();
```

The idea is to set the `.nextval` sequence for a given table back to an arbitrary number (but always more than `minval`).

Comment: `alter sequence` is DDL.  You cannot use bind variables in DDL.  You would need to dynamically build the DDL statement you want and execute that and it wouldn't make sense to use a `PreparedStatement` to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JustinCave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397)'s comment was most illuminating:

> `alter sequence` is DDL. You cannot use bind variables in DDL. You would need to dynamically build the DDL statement you want and execute that and it wouldn't make sense to use a PreparedStatement to do so.

Recognizing that there are better ways to do it, but acknowledging time constraints, I constructed the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE %s INCREMENT BY %d
```

which works like a charm. Yes, the number to advance by is hardcoded in each request. Not the best solution but I cannot create stored procedures at this point, so it'll have to do.

Thank you Justin.